# Is there a way to disable an app's settings on an IOS or Android OS generated settings form?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, settings

Is there way to disable settings or make them immutable/readonly like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXErb.png), but for app settings?

We are using Angular, Ionic, Cordova environment. We were using a disable tag in the browser like this

```
<ion-item class="settings-item" *ngSwitchCase="'password'">
          <ion-label class="settings-label">{{field.name}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" class="settings-field" disabled={{field.overridden}} [(ngModel)]="field.value" [attr.data-e2e]="field.key"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

But unfortunately, this only works on the browser not on a device

This is my first post on StackOverFlow, please be gentle with the voting. If you see a problem with the question/body please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Not if the OS is handling the settings - which is what we were doing.

The form that is used that has the disabled tag has nothing to do with the forms that are generated by Android and IOS from the developer settings.json file we had.

Currently there is very little if any support for read-only settings. The picture I gave was something that Apple disabled themselves, but not a third-party app like ours is.

Edit: Of course, if you are disabling settings from a form that you created (not IOS or Android OS), then you **can** disable fields